# I have a Netapp that I want to backup for off site backup/DR

Tags: linux, backup, netapp

We use mixed CIFS and NFS volumes and I want to run a single backup server that copies all of the files from the NetAPP to local disks that can be sent of site for backup/DR.

How would I configure the NetAPP to allow me to read everything on both CIFS and NFS filesystems so that they can be backed up with rsync.  I've tried a few different configurations and I even submitted a ticket with NetApp but so far I don't have the NetApp configured correctly so I frequently get access denied.

Answer (score 1):

For NFS access, you don't necessarily need rsync....just remotely mount the disks and do the copy on the remote server....you can use rsync, strongly suggest that you examine the man page.

You can also mount CIFS shares on either a Windows box and easily backup that using Windows version of rsync.  Of course, there are Linux/UNIX routes here.

Have you considered getting a  Netapp at the remote location.  Then you could easily use the snapmirror feature.  This is what is generally done at most locations that I am aware of.  Thus it handles everything under one system.  Makes restores easier too.